# How to sort a list of characters based on their frequency in another string using python?

Tags: python, sorting

In python, how can I sort the characters in the following string based on the number of times each character appears ? An example text I want to sort is -

```
uwlcnfcejefjudkmylhmmpjfkmhveozojepfvgboboxknkfdoghkvzxrkamhaghahpnnzh_figzhelkapd_dnxsiurbjgq_bcctqgigfksdrzgtxvihiqvfvinuqfzgohvilwyxpuqjolleuecpxcbisaptnoxbglpkhsvvwdgaminprfrha_uemwdepnngtxgkqx_flerkbnnzazcvnh_sealovrpuafumrmaizidjedvovhtbadjelfrbknpioqiindxqiozzpdrv_bwooblumjc_oqtcgrfmxkwkczhhqiwuqzoznqgfmbdxrxigvkebypbsybanuccpsezgv_dvteybbrbrbldbpiyhgzkptloxfktrzkjmdhppucsaohfnehdnlnhexwj_yhulslwpdreogjsffy_fkqcdkobywhqxpjvv_sqbscknxrew_ivgvpolmqfkyxoxzuyqctriyxcncwvvqhdupkagguee_zfbcrexbtkcsbnjcfzqoq_wrdktpsclzrmeybxpzrylfdydknd_zbjjqcnubpjbfaaecuxbeprjjjfcybvcghfbcvnjicpliwzkqvwo_hloynyjrmiqvubsyobetklnsgovesswqatrcrirsywdvbpwnhtjaug_nglxamsybkop_gnkdvgzp_cmyxclrtjtoohniuszzbnakknd_ahe_enbouxvpueotcjebex_vpqbwyjgczobcirmgfvwnlrxaryoltdlozwdgcp__iwu_vkod_kzkmeklloeixrxymlvyvtlfyydwtzxugrhxwqgmmsvtshrublypevlpglldlumsbscjuv_cbtfjpenrervyxtbrxaaqsqs__boiiubqmgwtvzxlnxxyskbwquztepk_uggukayehrifcrdpcnrfhmlucqzbsvoojsfexvbzsrccyqjuufbiae_siovpbhhqzkcemm_wtzio_d_emtkxpkpqftqjrhiiuvyijtwrmj_r_nlsaqemp_yph_murlmwwibzxnerld_fracudoxwqsmjkdvbfbnmkvktrkyyoct_woymzxswtd_dvs_joviugjjvswlltkforlv_xdokzbqkzrojvevuuzkpcvvaarca_oeryyuasilqpwrzkyrsbskjnywidkcefjdekawqutrihusqtq_bjaaysidwvpmhozxcsacpehceplbihgnuaucvatj_prb_fflzfyyrndrxq__ptxkcbhhslnuuwljwxbxzbujntztebr_knnffhl_cvxowdtpxldvsonhnfxxnmwopu_tgosofhhjhmxkdnvorwlsxy_cleasbnonadrgxf_bzipudfonthlclvnhumrbjkdryoawoz__ttftltixhdhd_qoteqmyehlulpffaqmughpxxsyeevncin_ymjsnndirfg_jjcltmgphlpudrjviaixlxnpwvr_bqygvuhoskhtv_pqnyzmjymrpnphebxqfpkfhzirotxayvclcr_zcrtsakfusyyujzdjgizngmonogwknjcndlpvktgntgajmzwcnkhggmhzijyrpbkpdcribyteyqchlldzeelebqjplphcdgpaaatdelz_khxpxqclexvlcjiyssgsgmsddclgmsae_eubvmscpjwascwegqdxvvh_zuteauydayapfamxilyugubce_kibquetsvlmguecrm_uojvkjammyevgxwfcfq_fjnauajadhsjvtsduzpmqecxfuqaaq__qhtvl_uurqaquuygypqxnhrnhhiwrufntlunfqwaydimaahiihvcaycinidodqzmrnxnnxdsquwc_u_zrrkscjv_jwsp_xfkupx_rcbzovpsbwyiumeaanyiaqromomqldfprejqnytjftdcklykzsdupl_makofxndacjbbftywdxmvmfv_wogpggfeivpfiqqlzcweelzclxkgqlvysuignftxqooofgvnopvtjy_udsf_wx_wloyznfixdeyxbvqljuncfmtvjhrrrpcxowggllwcmzlp_bgwpepdntxzjbqprgdtpdbtofhwknqdarbqvryfaiq_lneqwlwpjpfxbmttidphupuhwghgafybhtulwkgpoavwbtixuvqroknoas_pvufqfanwdvzraqpxudodpifa_s_xiaef_abeawgaamorlogpmmavrwbt_bzthsnzaxzitbyuohtqswnqekujrojerffenhkna_nyioesdgaeofpuoyoybuweuswzaraanyzkaxuncumlsnzoavkmjoejygohgtrqtdouiubigjhrutk
```

Once sorted, I have to drop all characters after (and including) the underscore character '_'

Here's what I have tried -

```
from collections import Counter


class Solution:
    def frequencySort(self, s: str, text: str) -> str:
        c = Counter(list(text))

        # Create a list to store characters from 's' sorted by frequency in 'text'
        sorted_chars = []

        # Iterate over the unique characters in 's'
        for char in set(s):
            # Repeat each character by its count in 's'
            sorted_chars.extend([char] * s.count(char))

        # Sort 'sorted_chars' in place using a loop
        for i in range(len(sorted_chars)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(sorted_chars)):
                if c[sorted_chars[j]] > c[sorted_chars[i]] or \
                        (c[sorted_chars[j]] == c[sorted_chars[i]] and sorted_chars[j] < sorted_chars[i]):
                    sorted_chars[i], sorted_chars[j] = sorted_chars[j], sorted_chars[i]

        # Join the sorted characters into a string
        output = ''.join(sorted_chars)

        return output


solution = Solution()
sorted_string = solution.frequencySort("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza_", """
uwlcnfcejefjudkmylhmmpjfkmhveozojepfvgboboxknkfdoghkvzxrkamhaghahpnnzh_figzhelkapd_dnxsiurbjgq_bcctqgigfksdrzgtxvihiqvfvinuqfzgohvilwyxpuqjolleuecpxcbisaptnoxbglpkhsvvwdgaminprfrha_uemwdepnngtxgkqx_flerkbnnzazcvnh_sealovrpuafumrmaizidjedvovhtbadjelfrbknpioqiindxqiozzpdrv_bwooblumjc_oqtcgrfmxkwkczhhqiwuqzoznqgfmbdxrxigvkebypbsybanuccpsezgv_dvteybbrbrbldbpiyhgzkptloxfktrzkjmdhppucsaohfnehdnlnhexwj_yhulslwpdreogjsffy_fkqcdkobywhqxpjvv_sqbscknxrew_ivgvpolmqfkyxoxzuyqctriyxcncwvvqhdupkagguee_zfbcrexbtkcsbnjcfzqoq_wrdktpsclzrmeybxpzrylfdydknd_zbjjqcnubpjbfaaecuxbeprjjjfcybvcghfbcvnjicpliwzkqvwo_hloynyjrmiqvubsyobetklnsgovesswqatrcrirsywdvbpwnhtjaug_nglxamsybkop_gnkdvgzp_cmyxclrtjtoohniuszzbnakknd_ahe_enbouxvpueotcjebex_vpqbwyjgczobcirmgfvwnlrxaryoltdlozwdgcp__iwu_vkod_kzkmeklloeixrxymlvyvtlfyydwtzxugrhxwqgmmsvtshrublypevlpglldlumsbscjuv_cbtfjpenrervyxtbrxaaqsqs__boiiubqmgwtvzxlnxxyskbwquztepk_uggukayehrifcrdpcnrfhmlucqzbsvoojsfexvbzsrccyqjuufbiae_siovpbhhqzkcemm_wtzio_d_emtkxpkpqftqjrhiiuvyijtwrmj_r_nlsaqemp_yph_murlmwwibzxnerld_fracudoxwqsmjkdvbfbnmkvktrkyyoct_woymzxswtd_dvs_joviugjjvswlltkforlv_xdokzbqkzrojvevuuzkpcvvaarca_oeryyuasilqpwrzkyrsbskjnywidkcefjdekawqutrihusqtq_bjaaysidwvpmhozxcsacpehceplbihgnuaucvatj_prb_fflzfyyrndrxq__ptxkcbhhslnuuwljwxbxzbujntztebr_knnffhl_cvxowdtpxldvsonhnfxxnmwopu_tgosofhhjhmxkdnvorwlsxy_cleasbnonadrgxf_bzipudfonthlclvnhumrbjkdryoawoz__ttftltixhdhd_qoteqmyehlulpffaqmughpxxsyeevncin_ymjsnndirfg_jjcltmgphlpudrjviaixlxnpwvr_bqygvuhoskhtv_pqnyzmjymrpnphebxqfpkfhzirotxayvclcr_zcrtsakfusyyujzdjgizngmonogwknjcndlpvktgntgajmzwcnkhggmhzijyrpbkpdcribyteyqchlldzeelebqjplphcdgpaaatdelz_khxpxqclexvlcjiyssgsgmsddclgmsae_eubvmscpjwascwegqdxvvh_zuteauydayapfamxilyugubce_kibquetsvlmguecrm_uojvkjammyevgxwfcfq_fjnauajadhsjvtsduzpmqecxfuqaaq__qhtvl_uurqaquuygypqxnhrnhhiwrufntlunfqwaydimaahiihvcaycinidodqzmrnxnnxdsquwc_u_zrrkscjv_jwsp_xfkupx_rcbzovpsbwyiumeaanyiaqromomqldfprejqnytjftdcklykzsdupl_makofxndacjbbftywdxmvmfv_wogpggfeivpfiqqlzcweelzclxkgqlvysuignftxqooofgvnopvtjy_udsf_wx_wloyznfixdeyxbvqljuncfmtvjhrrrpcxowggllwcmzlp_bgwpepdntxzjbqprgdtpdbtofhwknqdarbqvryfaiq_lneqwlwpjpfxbmttidphupuhwghgafybhtulwkgpoavwbtixuvqroknoas_pvufqfanwdvzraqpxudodpifa_s_xiaef_abeawgaamorlogpmmavrwbt_bzthsnzaxzitbyuohtqswnqekujrojerffenhkna_nyioesdgaeofpuoyoybuweuswzaraanyzkaxuncumlsnzoavkmjoejygohgtrqtdouiubigjhrutk ...
""")

answer = sorted_string.split('_')[0]
print(answer)
```

Comment: You haven't **asked a question**...

Comment: If a letter appears for the same number of times as the underscore, does it get sorted before or after the underscore, which decides if it should be dropped?

Answer (score 1):

I used  counter and collections to solve the issue. It is working ok.

```
from collections import Counter

def sort_string_by_frequency(s, text):
    c = Counter(text)
    sorted_chars = sorted(s, key=lambda char: (-c[char], char))
    sorted_string = ''.join(sorted_chars)
    answer = sorted_string.split('_')[0]

    return answer

s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza_"
text = "uwlcnfcejefjudkmylhmmpjfkmhveozojepfvgboboxknkfdoghkvzxrkamhaghahpnnzh_figzhelkapd_dnxsiurbjgq_bcctqgigfksdrzgtxvihiqvfvinuqfzgohvilwyxpuqjolleuecpxcbisaptnoxbglpkhsvvwdgaminprfrha_uemwdepnngtxgkqx_flerkbnnzazcvnh_sealovrpuafumrmaizidjedvovhtbadjelfrbknpioqiindxqiozzpdrv_bwooblumjc_oqtcgrfmxkwkczhhqiwuqzoznqgfmbdxrxigvkebypbsybanuccpsezgv_dvteybbrbrbldbpiyhgzkptloxfktrzkjmdhppucsaohfnehdnlnhexwj_yhulslwpdreogjsffy_fkqcdkobywhqxpjvv_sqbscknxrew_ivgvpolmqfkyxoxzuyqctriyxcncwvvqhdupkagguee_zfbcrexbtkcsbnjcfzqoq_wrdktpsclzrmeybxpzrylfdydknd_zbjjqcnubpjbfaaecuxbeprjjjfcybvcghfbcvnjicpliwzkqvwo_hloynyjrmiqvubsyobetklnsgovesswqatrcrirsywdvbpwnhtjaug_nglxamsybkop_gnkdvgzp_cmyxclrtjtoohniuszzbnakknd_ahe_enbouxvpueotcjebex_vpqbwyjgczobcirmgfvwnlrxaryoltdlozwdgcp__iwu_vkod_kzkmeklloeixrxymlvyvtlfyydwtzxugrhxwqgmmsvtshrublypevlpglldlumsbscjuv_cbtfjpenrervyxtbrxaaqsqs__boiiubqmgwtvzxlnxxyskbwquztepk_uggukayehrifcrdpcnrfhmlucqzbsvoojsfexvbzsrccyqjuufbiae_siovpbhhqzkcemm_wtzio_d_emtkxpkpqftqjrhiiuvyijtwrmj_r_nlsaqemp_yph_murlmwwibzxnerld_fracudoxwqsmjkdvbfbnmkvktrkyyoct_woymzxswtd_dvs_joviugjjvswlltkforlv_xdokzbqkzrojvevuuzkpcvvaarca_oeryyuasilqpwrzkyrsbskjnywidkcefjdekawqutrihusqtq_bjaaysidwvpmhozxcsacpehceplbihgnuaucvatj_prb_fflzfyyrndrxq__ptxkcbhhslnuuwljwxbxzbujntztebr_knnffhl_cvxowdtpxldvsonhnfxxnmwopu_tgosofhhjhmxkdnvorwlsxy_cleasbnonadrgxf_bzipudfonthlclvnhumrbjkdryoawoz__ttftltixhdhd_qoteqmyehlulpffaqmughpxxsyeevncin_ymjsnndirfg_jjcltmgphlpudrjviaixlxnpwvr_bqygvuhoskhtv_pqnyzmjymrpnphebxqfpkfhzirotxayvclcr_zcrtsakfusyyujzdjgizngmonogwknjcndlpvktgntgajmzwcnkhggmhzijyrpbkpdcribyteyqchlldzeelebqjplphcdgpaaatdelz_khxpxqclexvlcjiyssgsgmsddclgmsae_eubvmscpjwascwegqdxvvh_zuteauydayapfamxilyugubce_kibquetsvlmguecrm_uojvkjammyevgxwfcfq_fjnauajadhsjvtsduzpmqecxfuqaaq__qhtvl_uurqaquuygypqxnhrnhhiwrufntlunfqwaydimaahiihvcaycinidodqzmrnxnnxdsquwc_u_zrrkscjv_jwsp_xfkupx_rcbzovpsbwyiumeaanyiaqromomqldfprejqnytjftdcklykzsdupl_makofxndacjbbftywdxmvmfv_wogpggfeivpfiqqlzcweelzclxkgqlvysuignftxqooofgvnopvtjy_udsf_wx_wloyznfixdeyxbvqljuncfmtvjhrrrpcxowggllwcmzlp_bgwpepdntxzjbqprgdtpdbtofhwknqdarbqvryfaiq_lneqwlwpjpfxbmttidphupuhwghgafybhtulwkgpoavwbtixuvqroknoas_pvufqfanwdvzraqpxudodpifa_s_xiaef_abeawgaamorlogpmmavrwbt_bzthsnzaxzitbyuohtqswnqekujrojerffenhkna_nyioesdgaeofpuoyoybuweuswzaraanyzkaxuncumlsnzoavkmjoejygohgtrqtdouiubigjhrutk"

result = sort_string_by_frequency(s, text)
print(result)
```

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Unfortunately your solution is wrong. There is a duplicate "a" in the result. I'm quite sure this is a result of the wrong definition of `s`.

Answer (score 1):

The *most_common()* method of the Counter class is ideal for this:

```
from collections import Counter

s = 'uwlcnfcejefjudkmylhmmpjfkmhveozojepfvgboboxknkfdoghkvzxrkamhaghahpnnzh_figzhelkapd_dnxsiurbjgq_bcctqgigfksdrzgtxvihiqvfvinuqfzgohvilwyxpuqjolleuecpxcbisaptnoxbglpkhsvvwdgaminprfrha_uemwdepnngtxgkqx_flerkbnnzazcvnh_sealovrpuafumrmaizidjedvovhtbadjelfrbknpioqiindxqiozzpdrv_bwooblumjc_oqtcgrfmxkwkczhhqiwuqzoznqgfmbdxrxigvkebypbsybanuccpsezgv_dvteybbrbrbldbpiyhgzkptloxfktrzkjmdhppucsaohfnehdnlnhexwj_yhulslwpdreogjsffy_fkqcdkobywhqxpjvv_sqbscknxrew_ivgvpolmqfkyxoxzuyqctriyxcncwvvqhdupkagguee_zfbcrexbtkcsbnjcfzqoq_wrdktpsclzrmeybxpzrylfdydknd_zbjjqcnubpjbfaaecuxbeprjjjfcybvcghfbcvnjicpliwzkqvwo_hloynyjrmiqvubsyobetklnsgovesswqatrcrirsywdvbpwnhtjaug_nglxamsybkop_gnkdvgzp_cmyxclrtjtoohniuszzbnakknd_ahe_enbouxvpueotcjebex_vpqbwyjgczobcirmgfvwnlrxaryoltdlozwdgcp__iwu_vkod_kzkmeklloeixrxymlvyvtlfyydwtzxugrhxwqgmmsvtshrublypevlpglldlumsbscjuv_cbtfjpenrervyxtbrxaaqsqs__boiiubqmgwtvzxlnxxyskbwquztepk_uggukayehrifcrdpcnrfhmlucqzbsvoojsfexvbzsrccyqjuufbiae_siovpbhhqzkcemm_wtzio_d_emtkxpkpqftqjrhiiuvyijtwrmj_r_nlsaqemp_yph_murlmwwibzxnerld_fracudoxwqsmjkdvbfbnmkvktrkyyoct_woymzxswtd_dvs_joviugjjvswlltkforlv_xdokzbqkzrojvevuuzkpcvvaarca_oeryyuasilqpwrzkyrsbskjnywidkcefjdekawqutrihusqtq_bjaaysidwvpmhozxcsacpehceplbihgnuaucvatj_prb_fflzfyyrndrxq__ptxkcbhhslnuuwljwxbxzbujntztebr_knnffhl_cvxowdtpxldvsonhnfxxnmwopu_tgosofhhjhmxkdnvorwlsxy_cleasbnonadrgxf_bzipudfonthlclvnhumrbjkdryoawoz__ttftltixhdhd_qoteqmyehlulpffaqmughpxxsyeevncin_ymjsnndirfg_jjcltmgphlpudrjviaixlxnpwvr_bqygvuhoskhtv_pqnyzmjymrpnphebxqfpkfhzirotxayvclcr_zcrtsakfusyyujzdjgizngmonogwknjcndlpvktgntgajmzwcnkhggmhzijyrpbkpdcribyteyqchlldzeelebqjplphcdgpaaatdelz_khxpxqclexvlcjiyssgsgmsddclgmsae_eubvmscpjwascwegqdxvvh_zuteauydayapfamxilyugubce_kibquetsvlmguecrm_uojvkjammyevgxwfcfq_fjnauajadhsjvtsduzpmqecxfuqaaq__qhtvl_uurqaquuygypqxnhrnhhiwrufntlunfqwaydimaahiihvcaycinidodqzmrnxnnxdsquwc_u_zrrkscjv_jwsp_xfkupx_rcbzovpsbwyiumeaanyiaqromomqldfprejqnytjftdcklykzsdupl_makofxndacjbbftywdxmvmfv_wogpggfeivpfiqqlzcweelzclxkgqlvysuignftxqooofgvnopvtjy_udsf_wx_wloyznfixdeyxbvqljuncfmtvjhrrrpcxowggllwcmzlp_bgwpepdntxzjbqprgdtpdbtofhwknqdarbqvryfaiq_lneqwlwpjpfxbmttidphupuhwghgafybhtulwkgpoavwbtixuvqroknoas_pvufqfanwdvzraqpxudodpifa_s_xiaef_abeawgaamorlogpmmavrwbt_bzthsnzaxzitbyuohtqswnqekujrojerffenhkna_nyioesdgaeofpuoyoybuweuswzaraanyzkaxuncumlsnzoavkmjoejygohgtrqtdouiubigjhrutk'

print(''.join([c for c, _ in Counter(s).most_common()]).split('_')[0])
```

**Output:**

```
unprovable
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved in 3 steps:

```
all_chars = 'uwlcnfcejefjudkmylhmmpjfkmhveozojepfvgboboxknkfdoghkvzxrkamhaghahpnnzh_figzhelkapd_dnxsiurbjgq_bcctqgigfksdrzgtxvihiqvfvinuqfzgohvilwyxpuqjolleuecpxcbisaptnoxbglpkhsvvwdgaminprfrha_uemwdepnngtxgkqx_flerkbnnzazcvnh_sealovrpuafumrmaizidjedvovhtbadjelfrbknpioqiindxqiozzpdrv_bwooblumjc_oqtcgrfmxkwkczhhqiwuqzoznqgfmbdxrxigvkebypbsybanuccpsezgv_dvteybbrbrbldbpiyhgzkptloxfktrzkjmdhppucsaohfnehdnlnhexwj_yhulslwpdreogjsffy_fkqcdkobywhqxpjvv_sqbscknxrew_ivgvpolmqfkyxoxzuyqctriyxcncwvvqhdupkagguee_zfbcrexbtkcsbnjcfzqoq_wrdktpsclzrmeybxpzrylfdydknd_zbjjqcnubpjbfaaecuxbeprjjjfcybvcghfbcvnjicpliwzkqvwo_hloynyjrmiqvubsyobetklnsgovesswqatrcrirsywdvbpwnhtjaug_nglxamsybkop_gnkdvgzp_cmyxclrtjtoohniuszzbnakknd_ahe_enbouxvpueotcjebex_vpqbwyjgczobcirmgfvwnlrxaryoltdlozwdgcp__iwu_vkod_kzkmeklloeixrxymlvyvtlfyydwtzxugrhxwqgmmsvtshrublypevlpglldlumsbscjuv_cbtfjpenrervyxtbrxaaqsqs__boiiubqmgwtvzxlnxxyskbwquztepk_uggukayehrifcrdpcnrfhmlucqzbsvoojsfexvbzsrccyqjuufbiae_siovpbhhqzkcemm_wtzio_d_emtkxpkpqftqjrhiiuvyijtwrmj_r_nlsaqemp_yph_murlmwwibzxnerld_fracudoxwqsmjkdvbfbnmkvktrkyyoct_woymzxswtd_dvs_joviugjjvswlltkforlv_xdokzbqkzrojvevuuzkpcvvaarca_oeryyuasilqpwrzkyrsbskjnywidkcefjdekawqutrihusqtq_bjaaysidwvpmhozxcsacpehceplbihgnuaucvatj_prb_fflzfyyrndrxq__ptxkcbhhslnuuwljwxbxzbujntztebr_knnffhl_cvxowdtpxldvsonhnfxxnmwopu_tgosofhhjhmxkdnvorwlsxy_cleasbnonadrgxf_bzipudfonthlclvnhumrbjkdryoawoz__ttftltixhdhd_qoteqmyehlulpffaqmughpxxsyeevncin_ymjsnndirfg_jjcltmgphlpudrjviaixlxnpwvr_bqygvuhoskhtv_pqnyzmjymrpnphebxqfpkfhzirotxayvclcr_zcrtsakfusyyujzdjgizngmonogwknjcndlpvktgntgajmzwcnkhggmhzijyrpbkpdcribyteyqchlldzeelebqjplphcdgpaaatdelz_khxpxqclexvlcjiyssgsgmsddclgmsae_eubvmscpjwascwegqdxvvh_zuteauydayapfamxilyugubce_kibquetsvlmguecrm_uojvkjammyevgxwfcfq_fjnauajadhsjvtsduzpmqecxfuqaaq__qhtvl_uurqaquuygypqxnhrnhhiwrufntlunfqwaydimaahiihvcaycinidodqzmrnxnnxdsquwc_u_zrrkscjv_jwsp_xfkupx_rcbzovpsbwyiumeaanyiaqromomqldfprejqnytjftdcklykzsdupl_makofxndacjbbftywdxmvmfv_wogpggfeivpfiqqlzcweelzclxkgqlvysuignftxqooofgvnopvtjy_udsf_wx_wloyznfixdeyxbvqljuncfmtvjhrrrpcxowggllwcmzlp_bgwpepdntxzjbqprgdtpdbtofhwknqdarbqvryfaiq_lneqwlwpjpfxbmttidphupuhwghgafybhtulwkgpoavwbtixuvqroknoas_pvufqfanwdvzraqpxudodpifa_s_xiaef_abeawgaamorlogpmmavrwbt_bzthsnzaxzitbyuohtqswnqekujrojerffenhkna_nyioesdgaeofpuoyoybuweuswzaraanyzkaxuncumlsnzoavkmjoejygohgtrqtdouiubigjhrutk'

# store in a dict the characters with the number of ocurrences
count_chars = {}
for c in all_chars:
    if c in count_chars:
        count_chars[c] += 1
    else:
        count_chars[c] = 1

# sort the dict by the values reversed
count_chars = dict(
    sorted(count_chars.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))

# get the chars until '_'
message = ''
for c in count_chars:
    if c == '_':
        break
    message += c

print(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

using `Counter` class,

```
# your code goes here
from collections import Counter

string = "uwlcnfcejefjudkmylhmmpjfkmhveozojepfvgboboxknkfdoghkvzxrkamhaghahpnnzh_figzhelkapd_dnxsiurbjgq_bcctqgigfksdrzgtxvihiqvfvinuqfzgohvilwyxpuqjolleuecpxcbisaptnoxbglpkhsvvwdgaminprfrha_uemwdepnngtxgkqx_flerkbnnzazcvnh_sealovrpuafumrmaizidjedvovhtbadjelfrbknpioqiindxqiozzpdrv_bwooblumjc_oqtcgrfmxkwkczhhqiwuqzoznqgfmbdxrxigvkebypbsybanuccpsezgv_dvteybbrbrbldbpiyhgzkptloxfktrzkjmdhppucsaohfnehdnlnhexwj_yhulslwpdreogjsffy_fkqcdkobywhqxpjvv_sqbscknxrew_ivgvpolmqfkyxoxzuyqctriyxcncwvvqhdupkagguee_zfbcrexbtkcsbnjcfzqoq_wrdktpsclzrmeybxpzrylfdydknd_zbjjqcnubpjbfaaecuxbeprjjjfcybvcghfbcvnjicpliwzkqvwo_hloynyjrmiqvubsyobetklnsgovesswqatrcrirsywdvbpwnhtjaug_nglxamsybkop_gnkdvgzp_cmyxclrtjtoohniuszzbnakknd_ahe_enbouxvpueotcjebex_vpqbwyjgczobcirmgfvwnlrxaryoltdlozwdgcp__iwu_vkod_kzkmeklloeixrxymlvyvtlfyydwtzxugrhxwqgmmsvtshrublypevlpglldlumsbscjuv_cbtfjpenrervyxtbrxaaqsqs__boiiubqmgwtvzxlnxxyskbwquztepk_uggukayehrifcrdpcnrfhmlucqzbsvoojsfexvbzsrccyqjuufbiae_siovpbhhqzkcemm_wtzio_d_emtkxpkpqftqjrhiiuvyijtwrmj_r_nlsaqemp_yph_murlmwwibzxnerld_fracudoxwqsmjkdvbfbnmkvktrkyyoct_woymzxswtd_dvs_joviugjjvswlltkforlv_xdokzbqkzrojvevuuzkpcvvaarca_oeryyuasilqpwrzkyrsbskjnywidkcefjdekawqutrihusqtq_bjaaysidwvpmhozxcsacpehceplbihgnuaucvatj_prb_fflzfyyrndrxq__ptxkcbhhslnuuwljwxbxzbujntztebr_knnffhl_cvxowdtpxldvsonhnfxxnmwopu_tgosofhhjhmxkdnvorwlsxy_cleasbnonadrgxf_bzipudfonthlclvnhumrbjkdryoawoz__ttftltixhdhd_qoteqmyehlulpffaqmughpxxsyeevncin_ymjsnndirfg_jjcltmgphlpudrjviaixlxnpwvr_bqygvuhoskhtv_pqnyzmjymrpnphebxqfpkfhzirotxayvclcr_zcrtsakfusyyujzdjgizngmonogwknjcndlpvktgntgajmzwcnkhggmhzijyrpbkpdcribyteyqchlldzeelebqjplphcdgpaaatdelz_khxpxqclexvlcjiyssgsgmsddclgmsae_eubvmscpjwascwegqdxvvh_zuteauydayapfamxilyugubce_kibquetsvlmguecrm_uojvkjammyevgxwfcfq_fjnauajadhsjvtsduzpmqecxfuqaaq__qhtvl_uurqaquuygypqxnhrnhhiwrufntlunfqwaydimaahiihvcaycinidodqzmrnxnnxdsquwc_u_zrrkscjv_jwsp_xfkupx_rcbzovpsbwyiumeaanyiaqromomqldfprejqnytjftdcklykzsdupl_makofxndacjbbftywdxmvmfv_wogpggfeivpfiqqlzcweelzclxkgqlvysuignftxqooofgvnopvtjy_udsf_wx_wloyznfixdeyxbvqljuncfmtvjhrrrpcxowggllwcmzlp_bgwpepdntxzjbqprgdtpdbtofhwknqdarbqvryfaiq_lneqwlwpjpfxbmttidphupuhwghgafybhtulwkgpoavwbtixuvqroknoas_pvufqfanwdvzraqpxudodpifa_s_xiaef_abeawgaamorlogpmmavrwbt_bzthsnzaxzitbyuohtqswnqekujrojerffenhkna_nyioesdgaeofpuoyoybuweuswzaraanyzkaxuncumlsnzoavkmjoejygohgtrqtdouiubigjhrutk"
freq = Counter(string)

most_commons = freq.most_common(len(freq))
result = []
for a, b in most_commons:
    if a == '_':
        break
    else:
        result.append(a)

sol = ''.join(result)

print(sol) # unprovable
```

Comment: @pho updated thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `Counter` collection can do a lot of heavy lifting here, as can `sorted` with a custom key:

```
from collections import Counter

# get frequencies from the text
counter = Counter(text)

# sort the string by text frequencies
sorted_string = ''.join(sorted(s, key=lambda ch: counter[ch], reverse=True))

# find the underscore and cut the string up to that position
result = sorted_string[0:sorted_string.find('_')]

result
# => 'unprovaable'
```

Note that this preserves all the characters in the input string that are more frequent than the underscore: since the input string has two `a` characters, two `a` characters are preserved in the output.